# How to remove the "deleting object" while i'm on certain distance

Tags: game-engine

When i start a standalone player when i go away there is a "fog" that delimits the level of detail. How i modify that?
[image]

Comment: looks like the Camera's far clipping plane is too close?

Comment: yes i forgot to remove this because i discovered, anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just increase the end clipping the camera option when yuo select the camera [image]